# R: Plotting multiple csv files independently in one time series plot (also importing csv files with conditions)

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, import, time-series

I am trying to end up with a time series plot comparing different cities with a `center` data (data frame).Where `center` is a dataframe object in R studio, I already imported.

I have a folder with 165 csv files, each representing a city. I want to plot all the 165 csv files (as independent names/data frame) in one plot plus the `center` data frame.

I want it to look something like this: (with the x-axis being time and the y-axis being CO with all being solid colors.

[image]

There are four things I want to do to each csv file, but in the end, have it automated that these four actions are done to each of the 165 csv files.

1) Skip the first 25 row of the csv file

2) Combine the Date and Time column for each csv file

3) Remove the rows where the values in the cells in column 3 is empty

4) Change the name of column 3 from ug/m3 to CO

I want it to perform the four actions on each of the 165 csv files in an automated way.Then, be able to efficiently plot the newly updated csv files in one plot.

I used the code below on one csv file to see if it would work on one csv. I am not sure how to combine everything in an efficient manner.achieve this:

```
city1 <- read.csv("path",
                        skip = 25)

city1$rtime <- strptime(paste(city1$Date, city1$Time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

colnames(city1)[3] <- "CO"

city[,3][!(is.na(city[,3]))] ## side note: help with this would be appreciated, I was unsure of what goes before the comma.
```

Overall, I want a plot like above with all the 165 cities (csv files). I need help placing the four actions on each csv file and plot them all in one plot.

For the plot,
I did this as an example:

```
ggplot(center, aes(rtime, CO)) + geom_smooth(aes(color="Center"))+
  geom_smooth(data=city1,aes(color="City1"))+
  labs(color="Legend")
```

**UPDATE**:
The csv file of each city seemed to have combined to create one line.I am not sure if I can post the exact output but it looked like the one below: with the pink line being cities and blue being center.x-axis time and y-axis being CO.I hope this helps.

Result of `unique(df.cleaned$cities)`

```
> unique(df.cleaned$cities)
 [1] "WFH4N_YEK04_PORTLAND_08AUG16_R1"
 [2] "WFH2N_QIM23_AUSTIN_30JUL16_R1" 
 [3] "WFH7N_QIM70_NEWYORK_20JUL16_R1"
 [4] "WFH3N_YEK28_NAMPA_23AUG16_R1"
 [5] "WFH9N_YEK18_MESA_12JUL16_R1"
 [6] "WFH6N_QIM10_OAKLAND_11AUG16_R1"
 [7] "WFH3N_YEK01_DETROIT_30AUG16_R1"
 [8] "WFH6N_YEK05_ATLANTA_30AUG16_R1"
 [9] "WFH1N_YEK32_LONGBEACH_01JUL16_R1"
[10] "WFH8N_YEK39_LOSANGELES_30AUG16_R1"
[11] "WFH5N_YEK59_BALTIMORE_31AUG16_R1"
[12] "WFH1N_QIM19_MEMPHIS_01JUL16_R1"
[13] "WFH0N_YEK2087_DENVER_09JUL16_R1"
[14] "WFH4N_QIM43_CLEVELAND_30AUG16_R1"
[15] "WFH8N_QIM65_HARTFORD_30AUG16_R1"
[16] "WFH2N_YEK66_SEATTLE_30AUG16_R1"
[17] "WFH0N_YEK17_SANJOSE_30AUG16_R1"
```

[image]

Comment: To automate the part of reading 165 csv files, you can get a vector of characters for all the csv file names, and then do lapply over the filenames. For example `file_names <- list.files(path ="your folder path", pattern = ".csv")` to get the filenames, and then `lapply(file_names, FUN = function(file){...})`

Comment: With the regex I posted, all of those will parse to "", since your city names are capitalized, not title case like the example you gave. If you don't try to extract the city name, but instead leave that column `cities` like that, your plot should have separate lines for each one, as given by `aes(colour = cities)`. Does that part work correctly?

Comment: @Brian I decided not to try the regex when I realized the example I had given was different.Without the adding regex, it still gave me one line.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce the error without some sample data then. Could you share 1-2 of the CSVs or are they too large?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fully `tidyverse` solution, so base R traditionalists, look away now.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
# or just library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data_frame(files = list.files(path = "./yourfilepath",    
                                pattern = "csv", 
                                full.names = T)) %>%
    mutate(dfs = map(files, read_csv, skip = 25)) %>%       
    unnest() %>% 
    mutate(cities = str_replace_all(files, "./yourfilepath/", ""),
           cities = str_replace_all(cities, ".csv", ""))
```

- This chunk first makes a list of all the files in the folder
  `yourfilepath` named ***.csv**.
- Then you use `purrr::map` to run the
  same function on each element of the `files` variable: `read_csv`,
  skipping the first 25 lines.
- Now you have a dataframe with 165 nested
  dataframes in the column `dfs`.
- `unnest()` expands these to full
  dataframes, repeating the `files` rows as needed.
- Then you can strip
  out the extra parts of the path from `files` to get your city names,
  assuming that the filename of the .CSV is the name of the city.

  - If
    you have the name of the city already in a column inside each .CSV,
    then you don't need the `mutate(cities = ...)` lines.

Now it's easy peasy to do the rest:

```
df.cleaned <- df %>%
  rename(CO = `ug/m3`) %>%
  filter( !is.na(CO)) %>%
  mutate(rtime = paste(Date, Time),
         rtime = mdy_hm(rtime))
```

And now use your plotting code, slightly updated:

```
ggplot(center, aes(rtime, CO)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(color="Center"))+
  geom_smooth(data = df.cleaned, aes(color = cities))+
  labs(color="Legend")
```

---

## Update with more regex

```
df.cleaned <- df.cleaned %>%
  group_by(files) %>%
  mutate(cities = str_c(str_extract_all(cities, 
                                  "[A-Z][a-z]+", 
                                  simplify = T), 
                        collapse = " "))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I wanted to ask a follow up question, in the case where the cites' name is embedded in the file name of the csv file like `UGF2N_GDUM122_Chicago_03FEB16_R1` ,`UGF2N_GDUM122_Chicago_03FEB16_R1`

Comment: Then you'll need to write some regex to strip out everything except for the name. Without seeing more examples, I can't really guess at what might help, but I'll post a possible first try in my answer.

Comment: @Brain.Sorry, I didn't finish commenting and press enter.                          Thank you for the answer.I wanted to ask a follow-up question, in the case where the cities' name is embedded in the file name of the csv file like `UGF2N_GDUM122_Chicago_03FEB16_R1`, `WCK60_UBST122_Austin_13NOV16_R1`and etc all with a different name but with the city embedded in it.Is there a way to extract the city name only.         Also, it's µg/m3 with the 3 raised. Is there a way to do it on R studio have the 3 raised? or it is possible to say replace column 3?

Comment: With regards to your second question, are you asking about labeling the plot with **µg/m^3**? Or are you asking about how to fix the name coming into R from the CSV? The code I posted above already renames that column to "CO".

Comment: @Brain I am asking the latter. The **µg/m^3** is the name of the column in the CSV file when I view it in Rstudio (where the **3** is raised) I am not sure how to replicate the raised portion. When I used µg/m3, this error occurred ``µg/m3` contains unknown variables`

Comment: If you copy and paste that string exactly from the file into a plain text document, like Notepad, does the 3 still show up raised? It's possible it's actually a **³**, which is a different character from **3**.

Comment: Thank you! ³ is what I was trying to do.

Comment: I updated my answer. That regex matches and extracts patterns where there's a capital letter followed by lower case letters, so hopefully that fits all your city names.

Comment: Also, if this solved your problem, please hit the check mark next to the vote buttons to accept the answer.

Comment: The ggplot section: I got a single line for cities(it seemed to have combined the data from the csv files). I was hoping for several lines through out the plot representing each of the cities (each csv file in the folder). Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: With `aes(color = cities)`, you should have gotten a separate line for each city. Can you post a picture of your output in your question?

Comment: Can you post `unique(df.cleaned$cities)`? The only way they'd be making a single line is if that column isn't differentiating between all the filenames; or if only one city was actually being read in successfully.